# Find which port is requested in Nginx server block with multiple listen ports

Tags: nginx

So say I have the following server block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 81;
    server_name default_server;
}
```

and now I want to apply a setting only for port 80.

How can I check whether a request is coming from port 80 or 81?

I want to end up having something like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 81;
    server_name default_server;

    if (post_requested == 80) {
        // apply request limit (for example)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the port as follows:

```
if ($server_port = 80) { ... }
```

Comment: That worked, thank you!